# Ruby on Rails: Find values based on has_many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, has-many

I have 2 models: nation (table nations) and majors (table majors). 
nations contains all the nations of the world and majors contains all the educational branches like Computer Science, Mechanical Engineering etc.
Both models have id and name fields and contain the following relationships.

Nation model (Nation.rb)
has_many :majors

Major model (Major.rb)
has_many :nations

I want to run a query like: Find all the majors where nation_id = x (where x is the id of nation).

How do I do this in rails?

I feel there should exist a table which contains a mapping like:

```
id major_id nation_id
1   1        1
2   1        2
3   2        1
.
.
.
```

where each major is mapped to the country to which it belongs and vice versa. 
I am new to rails and not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about creating a third table for the mapping between the two. You have two options. You can either create a third table in case you want fields in it other than major_id and nation_id.

If not, you should go with creation of the join table. Feel free to try it and let me know if their are other issues.[This](http://jeffthomas.xyz/many-to-many-relationships-in-rails) article explains it in a very simple way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this :)

Comment: The tutorial was quite helpful. Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped. :)